# Change pandas dataframe content in a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pass-by-reference

I'm writing a class that does one hot encoding, but it doesn't work as I expected.

On my main code I have this:

```
for col in train_x_categorical.columns:
   dataCleaner.addFeatureToBeOneHotEncoded(col)

dataCleaner.applyOneHotEncoding(train_x_categorical)

train_x_categorical.head()
```

The class method is the following:

```
def addFeatureToBeOneHotEncoded(self, featureName):
    self._featuresToBeOneHotEncoded.append(featureName)

def applyOneHotEncoding(self, data):
    for feature in self._featuresToBeOneHotEncoded:
        dummies = pd.get_dummies(data[feature])
        dummies.drop(dummies.columns[-1],axis=1,inplace=True) 
        data.drop(feature, axis=1, inplace=True) 
        data = pd.concat([data, dummies], axis=1)
        print(data.columns)
```

Now, with `print(data.columns)` I can see that the method works correctly, but when `train_x_categorical.head()` runs I can't see the effect of the method `applyOneHotEncoding`.

I don't understand why this is happening and how to fix it.
I thought that since python passes values by reference, the variable `data` points to the same object as the variable `train_x_categorical`, so in the method `applyOneHotEncoding` I was working on the same object, but clearly I am wrong.
Can someone explain to me why my reasoning is wrong and how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `applyOneHotEncoding` updates the reference variable - `data`.  That doesn't work the way you think it does.  This is a well-known feature in Python.  There are a couple of ways around this that I know of - one is to have your method return the value.  That won't work in your case since you are doing this as part of a loop.  The other option is to put the variable to be updated in a wrapper class and pass that to the method. Then updating the variable that is part of the wrapper class will work.

See this for an exhaustive discussion:  [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)